# Python: Looping a certain amount of time in order different process

Tags: python, if-statement, tkinter

I made a script which is suppose to use Tkinter to allow to choose and load files and store their content in different objects and then process each of these documents.
I would like to make the script able to process only a certain amount of documents determined by a question (the value is stored under "File_number")
For exemple: if at the question "how many files do you want to compare?"
the user enter 3
I would like the tkinter openfile window to ask only for 3 files then keep going

I am using the If Else statement like below
but it doesn't seem to work well and the code is really not pythonic.
Is there a better/shorter way to perform the same?

Thanks

My script look like this

```
import pandas as pd
from pandas import *
import numpy as np
from scipy import stats
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import seaborn as sns
import pylab
import pandas.io.data
import os
import Tkinter
from Tkinter import *
import tkFileDialog
import tkSimpleDialog
from tkFileDialog import askopenfilename
import sys

# Set up GUI
root = Tkinter.Tk(); root.withdraw()

# Prompt for user info
File_number = tkSimpleDialog.askinteger("File number", "How many files do you want to compare?")


# Prompt for file explorer
# Also extract the file_name

process_a = 0

if process_a = File_number:
    break
else:
    process_a = process_a + 1
    fileloc1 = tkFileDialog.askopenfilename(parent=root, title='Choose file 1')
    fileloc1_name_clean = os.path.splitext(fileloc1)[0]
    fileloc1_name = os.path.basename(fileloc1_name_clean)

if process_a = File_number:
    break
else:
    process_a = process_a + 1
    fileloc2 = tkFileDialog.askopenfilename(parent=root, title='Choose file 2')
    fileloc2_name_clean = os.path.splitext(fileloc2)[0]
    fileloc2_name = os.path.basename(fileloc2_name_clean)

if process_a = File_number:
    break
else:
    process_a = process_a + 1
    fileloc3 = tkFileDialog.askopenfilename(parent=root, title='Choose file 3')
    fileloc3_name_clean = os.path.splitext(fileloc3)[0]
    fileloc3_name = os.path.basename(fileloc3_name_clean)
```

EDIT 1

```
The next part of my script is:

dfa_1 = pd.read_csv(fileloc1, delimiter='\t')
dfa_nodupli = dfa_1.drop_duplicates(cols='N', take_last=False)    
dfa_nodu_2pep = dfa_nodupli[(dfa_nodupli['Peptides(95%)'] > 1)]   
dfa_nodu_2pep = dfa_nodu_2pep[~dfa_nodu_2pep['Name'].str.contains('Keratin')]
dfa_nodu_2pep.to_csv(fileloc1_name + ".csv")



dfb_1 = pd.read_csv(fileloc2, delimiter='\t')
dfb_nodupli = dfb_1.drop_duplicates(cols='N', take_last=False)    
dfb_nodu_2pep = dfb_nodupli[(dfb_nodupli['Peptides(95%)'] > 1)]   
dfb_nodu_2pep = dfb_nodu_2pep[~dfb_nodu_2pep['Name'].str.contains('Keratin')]
dfb_nodu_2pep.to_csv(fileloc2_name + ".csv")
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I modified your code, so that it works, in a way you want it ( I hope).

```
import Tkinter
import tkFileDialog
import tkSimpleDialog
from tkFileDialog import askopenfilename
import os

# Set up GUI


def main():

    root = Tkinter.Tk(); 
    root.withdraw()

    # Prompt for user info
    File_number = tkSimpleDialog.askinteger("File number", 
                                            "How many files do you want to compare?")

    if not File_number:
        return

    user_fiels = []


    max_file_no = int(File_number)
    current_file = 1;

    while(current_file <= max_file_no):

        fileloc = tkFileDialog.askopenfilename(parent=root, title='Choose file {}'.format(current_file))

        if not fileloc:
            continue

        fileloc_name_clean = os.path.splitext(fileloc)[0]
        fileloc_name = os.path.basename(fileloc_name_clean)

        user_fiels.append([fileloc, fileloc_name_clean, fileloc_name])

        current_file += 1

        #print(fileloc_name_clean, fileloc_name)

    print(user_fiels) 

main()
```

I use while loop to get file paths as many times as you want.

Comment: Thanks Marcin, Your while loop is very interesting and indeed make Tkinter work for the specified number of document. However it is not exactly what I am looking for as I need to make a different fileloc (fileloc1, fileloc2) each of them with their corresponding path.basename because I call them later on in the script to create one dataframe per file selected and then use the basename for the output (On Edit 1)
Is there any way with your while method to link each file opened with a different fileloc and then create and process a number of dataframe equal to the previously selected number?

Comment: All files selected are stored in the list: `user_fiels`. After the while loop finishes, you can get the file paths from the list and do whatever you want with them.

Comment: Thanks, 
I will see how to access the last 'value' of each field in the list
and then use that to make a loop to create a different dataframe with each of them
It won't be a easy task for me as i'm still beginning in Python and i'm not very familiar with the possibilities in Loop.